# how to specify asset_host in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, actionmailer, amazon-cloudfront, ruby-2.1

I am using Amazon S3 for file uploads and Cloudfront for serving static assets, and in my config/environments/staging.rb, i wrote

```
ActionController::Base.asset_host = Proc.new { |source|
  if source.include?('/assets')
    "d1xw0c7m8has5k.cloudfront.net"
  else
    "#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
  end
}

ActionMailer::Base.asset_host = Proc.new { |source|
  if source.include?('/assets')
    "d1xw0c7m8has5k.cloudfront.net"
  else
    "#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
  end
}
```

but in my my mail send by rails application i see image_tag `src` attribute empty?
i.e. no image displayed.
what wrong with this setting i could not identify, please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I solve this issue by putting these configuration in the block in config/environments/staging.rb

```
Demo::Application.configure do
  config.action_controller.asset_host = Proc.new { |source|
    if source.include?('/assets')
      "d1xw0c7m8has5k.cloudfront.net"
    else
      "#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
    end
  }

  config.action_mailer.asset_host = Proc.new { |source|
    if source.include?('/assets')
      "http://d1xw0c7m8has5k.cloudfront.net"
    else
      "http://#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
    end
  }

end
```

and it is necessary to provide protocol with action_mailer asset_host, i.e 'HTTP'